# Socket.io socket.on triggers for each browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

When `completed` I have an alert with `message`;

```
socket.on("test-channel:completed", function (message) {
        alert(message);
    });
```

The problem is that it triggers for every tab in my browser that is on my website. Example: If I have 4 tabs on my website, I get 4 alerts.

**How can I make the alert trigger only once?**

Comment: How about only showing the `alert()` if the current tab has the focus and is visible?  Other than something like that, you will have to use multi-window communication somehow (either via localStorage or messaging) to indicate that some other tab has already shown the message.  I'd also hope that you're not actually using an `alert()` in production code as their modality can really mess things up on a browser.

Comment: @jfriend00 `alert()` is an example. Your idea could work. Do you have any answer to submit?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in this way.
You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
socket.on("test-channel:completed", function (message) {

        if(localStorage.getItem('alert')){

            //do not alert
        }else{

            localStorage.setItem('alert',true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It does not work. It get alert on all tab then set to true.